# Why doesn't this make two closures that behave differently?

Tags: python-2.7, closures

In this code:

```
> python
>>> a = []
>>> for i in range(2):
...     def printer():
...          print i
...     a.append(printer)
...
>>> a
[<function printer at 0x01EDE330>, <function printer at 0x01EDE2F0>]
>>> a[0]()
1
>>> a[1]()
1
>>>
>>> a[0] == a[1]
False
```

it appears that I made two different functions, and stored them in the array `a[]`.

I don't understand why the functions appear to be different, but the result of each function is not.   I would have thought either the functions would be the same (IE the second iteration would redefine the one from the first), or the functions would be different **and** the result would be different (0 and 1 respectively).

I hoping for and expecting the latter...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Thanks for quickly pointing me in in the right direction, and for your excellent answer in the other question.  I wonder if you would consider taking this question off "duplicate" and allowing an answer here.   The reason is that while it's a great answer, it's a convoluted question, and so the workaround examples are also convoluted.   If you don't know about partials already, its a bit tricky to untangle the workaround from the question code.   An answer here, of the same form, could allow for more clarity.

Comment: There are more duplicates linked from the sidebar, many with answers.

Comment: There are no duplicates of this question appearing in my sidebar, other than the one you linked to.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the one I linked you to. There currently are 87 posts linked there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/12423614?lq=1

Comment: Hah - my mistake, thanks!